# Dosent load the empty cells from listbox VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, commandbutton

I have a CommandButton to load the results from listbox(lsbWarenausgang) to the sheet (Tabelle5) but the button loads the results and all the empty results in excel table.

[image]

```
 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
 Dim lRw As Long
     Dim iX As Integer, iY As Integer
     For iX = 0 To lsbWarenausgang.ListCount - 1
         If Me.lsbWarenausgang.Selected(iX) = True Then
             With Tabelle5
                 lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                For iY = 0 To Me.lsbWarenausgang.ColumnCount - 1
                     .Cells(lRw, iY + 1).Value = Me.lsbWarenausgang.List(iX, iY)
            Next iY
        End With

    End If
Next iX
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this (**Untested**)? I am assuming that the first column will always be filled if there is data in that listbox row.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim lRw As Long
    Dim iX As Integer, iY As Integer
    Dim col As Long

    For iX = 0 To lsbWarenausgang.ListCount - 1
        col = 1
        If Me.lsbWarenausgang.Selected(iX) = True Then
            With Tabelle5
                If Len(Trim(Me.lsbWarenausgang.List(iX, 0))) <> 0 Then
                    lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

                    For iY = 0 To Me.lsbWarenausgang.ColumnCount - 1
                        If Len(Trim(Me.lsbWarenausgang.List(iX, iY))) <> 0 Then
                            .Cells(lRw, col).Value = Me.lsbWarenausgang.List(iX, iY)
                            col = col + 1
                        End If
                    Next iY
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next iX
End Sub
```

Comment: thets work great but the columna A its a step over then B ,C ,D

Comment: Oh so you dont want to step over? I have updated the code above. Now try it.. You may have to refresh the page to see the edit

Comment: from foto for exapmle the number in foto 88 load to A2  and all another things like data and another load to B3,C3 E3 how to mack it load all to seam column